# Exercise question in a Raymond Chen's article about mutexes in Windows

Tags: windows, linked-list, mutex, shared-memory

I have read Raymond Chen's article named "Understanding the consequences of WAIT_ABANDONED".
You may find it in [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050912-14/?p=34253)

My question is about the exercise part at the end of it. It says,

> Why did we use indices instead of pointers in our linked list data structure?

I think it is because linked list is probably shared between multiple processes and each have its own private address block. So using pointers to implement linked list which is accessed across multiple processes is pointless since they know nothing about each others' virtual addresses.

Am I right? If no, then what is the reason? If yes, is there any other important reason using indices instead of pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are correct.

If Microsoft had the ability to keep a blog platform working for more than a couple of years at a time without breaking links the research would be easier.

Looking at the original post with comments [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190117120112/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050912-14/?p=34253), most people have the same idea.

The only follow up I can [find](https://web.archive.org/web/20190216205851/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20081027-00/?p=20453) does not mention the exercise.

Raymond does post here on SO so maybe you will get lucky and he can confirm the answer...